# How to check successful connection to a SQL Server database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server database in C#, and check that the database contains an empty table with 3 columns, but I don't know how to check if it is successful or not..

My code:

```
protected bool checkDB()
{ 
    string ConnectionString = "Server=[serverName];Database=[databaseName];Trusted_Connection=true";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", con);

    // use the connection here
    con.Open();

    con.Close();

    if (success)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get exception on "con.Open();", then your connection is success...

Comment: @x... how to check the exception? use ` try{}catch{}`?

Comment: yes, try {..... return true;} catch { return false; }

Comment: one more question, i have a "\" in the server name, can i use "\\" to replace it?

Comment: You can see lots of sample here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: you can read here about exception handling http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/40/exception-handling#t=201607280338470828471

Comment: don't need "\\" , just "\" . Hope helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected bool checkDB()
{
  var connString = @"Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=true;";
  try
  {
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
      con.Open();
      using (var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", con))
      {
        // use your query here...
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, i am using windows authentication to connect sql server, so i don't know the username and password.. what should i do?

Comment: in fact i got an error about ---     A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: For windows auth use : Integrated Security=true;, without username and password

Comment: Test your connection using SQL Server Management Studio, sometimes you need to define port number 1433 for that, otherwise sql server port will be dynamic.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx add 1433 to TCP Port

Comment: now i am using  Integrated Security=true; However, i got an error about `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.` does it mean that i cannot login to the database?

Comment: Test that user "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" using sql management studio. If not working, than that user has a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957443/web-app-getting-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon

Comment: I can login with windows authentication by entering noting about user name and password (disable to enter text, but the text box of userName contains my account, the text box of password is empty)

Comment: Check that link before, sorry, never had something like that. Google it... lots of answer there.

Comment: The account you are running the application under is not your user account and does not have access to the database. Either open management studio and create a user that maps to the NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN Windows account (bad idea), change whatever context is running your application to use an account that also has access to the database (like yours), or just create a database user for your application and use that in the connection string instead of Windows auth.