# Converting to SSL Trashing datasource

Tags: ssl

Got my web site pretty much set the way I needed it and so went ahead and converted the site to SSL installing a certificate and then rebuilt my project and pushed it up to the sub folder figuring that would be it.  It wasn't the case!

What I have is a two tier'd web site with a landing site that is Anonymous and then a application sub site in a subfolder which uses Windows authentication. The landing site/page works fine yet but when you click on the link to launch the web app and initiate the web app in the sub folder where the Windows authentication is taking place, you are prompted for credentials as you should but upon validation you get this error:

```
Server Error in '/CInTrac' Application.

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information   
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for 
user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current 
web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception 
can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 
Stack Trace: 

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.]
```

Now admittedly this is my first time setting up SSL so I'm sure that there are things that I could be missing here and so I've likely made some mistakes here but what one earth would cause this to act this way. There is no anonymous calls in the code at all and this runs fine in VS on the desktop. It did run fine prior to setting up the certificate on the server

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Ken...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957443/web-app-getting-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had to switch to using Basic Authentication with ASP.NET Impersonation enabled (Impersonating the authenticated user) in order to get this to work with the SSL certificate in place. After doing so all was fine.