# Connecting SQL through Windows Authentication (Different server)

Tags: sql-server, iis, networking, dns, windows-authentication

I want to connect the SQL Server with Windows authentication but

1. Database is on a different server
2. IIS(Application) is on a different server(Both on the same network/domain)
3. Want to connect the database through windows authentication.

What configuration/settings I need to do to enable this? At present, When I log in through the application, I'm getting this error message

"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web App getting Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957443/web-app-getting-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks! :)

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: I think mine is different than the "Double Hop issue" Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you show me your web.config file?